# How to deny a user from viewing selected table in sql?

Tags: sql-server, object, permissions, linked-server

I have following tables in my database

```
EMPLOYEE
BADGE
EMPREC
BADGEACCESS
```

I created a user called **VMVN**, i want to restrict this user from seeing *BADGEACCESS*  table while others table remains unchanged

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `DENY` should work

```
 DENY SELECT ON OBJECT::BADGEACCESS TO [VMVN]
```

Comment: `Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.`

Comment: In that case your user will be either sysadmin on the server or db owner . For such user you can't DENY

Comment: now i created a new user `vmad`  with public role and while runnning the query its returning    `Cannot find the object 'BADGEACCESS', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
`

Comment: include the schema and check  OBJECT::<SCHEMA_NAME>.BADGEACCESS

Comment: how to find schema name, i believe my schema is dbo  buts its giving the same error. how do i check its its my schema

Comment: `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` , it returns empty .

Comment: @coffemug this is the right way to handle this. Are you logging in as the new user and trying to execute the deny statement?

Comment: @SeanLange ,  Now I created a new user with a public role and denied a single table using the above tsql . unfortunately, all the tables are not displaying for the user

Comment: Does the public role have other denys? Remember deny always trumps grant. You would have to provide a LOT more detail here for others to understand what is happening.

Comment: @SeanLange , this issue was solved . I gave datareader  and public roles to the user and then executed the  deny permission for a single table. that way when the user logins the denied table is hidden from them,

Comment: @SeanLange , anyother way to do it